# Fill missing value by averaging previous row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to fill missing value with the average of previous `N` row value, example is shown below:

```
N=2
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                    [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                    [np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan]],
                    columns=list('ABCD'))
```

DataFrame is like:

```
     A   B   C  D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0 NaN NaN
```

Result should be:

```
     A   B       C  D
0   NaN 2.0     NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0     NaN 1
2   NaN (4+2)/2 NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0     NaN (1+5)/2
```

I am wondering if there is elegant and fast way to achieve this without for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) + `mean` + `shift`

You will need to modify the below logic to interpret the mean of `NaN` and another value, in the case where one of the previous two values are null.

```
df = df.fillna(df.rolling(2).mean().shift())

print(df)

     A    B   C    D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1.0
2  NaN  3.0 NaN  5.0
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  3.0
```

Comment: seems rolling(2) will not consider the all previous n values if the rows are greater than 4 :-| @jpp

Comment: @NagaKiran, Yes, it does. The issue is with `NaN` treatment. OP hasn't defined what the average of `NaN` and another value should be, so I haven't second-guessed.